# Why do alternate delimiters not work with sed -e '/pattern/s/a/b/'?

Tags: sed

Here is something I have discover that doesn't make sense.

Output of `cat config.h`:

```
define somevar foo // Sample variable
```

This version of the command works to change foo to bar and preserve the comments:

```
sed -e '/somevar/s/foo/bar/' config.h
```

This doesn't work:

```
sed -e '|somevar|s|foo|bar|' config.h
```

Gives this error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `|'

Funnily enough this does work:

```
sed -e '/somevar/s|foo|bar|' config.h
```

Perhaps I am missing some part of the documentation. It seems very odd to have two different delimiters in the same sed command.

Bug or feature?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This will work:

```
sed -e '\|somevar|s|foo|bar|'
```

The `man` page of GNU sed is pretty clear about this:

```
   /regexp/
          Match lines matching the regular expression regexp.

   \cregexpc
          Match lines matching the regular expression regexp.  The  c  may
          be any character.
```

That is, the `c` may be any character, but the starting `\` is mandatory.

I don't have a FreeBSD around, but according to [@bonsaiviking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1183387/bonsaiviking) the `man` page there is also very clear:

> The opening delimiter needs to be preceded by a backslash unless it is a slash.

On the other hand in OSX this is not clear at all:

```
      In a context address, any character other than a backslash (``\'')
      or newline character may be used to delimit the regular expression.
      Also, putting a backslash character before the delimiting character
      causes the character to be treated literally.  For example, in the
      context address \xabc\xdefx, the RE delimiter is an ``x'' and the
      second ``x'' stands for itself, so that the regular expression is
      ``abcxdef''.
```

Notice that the example there uses `\xpatternx` instead of just `xpatternx`. That's all the clue it gives, it doesn't make it clear that `xpatternx` won't work.

Based on the argument of [@that-other-guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy), it makes sense that `sed` (and other languages like `perl` as [@Birei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/773159/birei) pointed out) need this extra clue to work correctly.

Comment: It's in [GNU sed's man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed), and FreeBSD's man page is clearer: "The opening delimiter needs to be preceded by a backslash unless it is a slash."

Comment: Thanks @bonsaiviking, I could check on Linux it's much more clear. I improved my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Allowing different delimiters for `/pattern/` would introduce parsing ambiguity.

Is `ispaghetti` supposed to be like `/spaghett/`, or is it supposed to insert text like `i spaghetti`?

With `s` and `y` there is no such ambiguity. When you see either of those characters, you know the command you're reading, and then you can interpret the next character as a delimiter.

We could resolve this ambiguity for `/pattern/` if we started it with a similarly recognizable character, and indeed sed has a separate address specifier for this: backslash, as in `\|pattern|` (this is not the same as escaping).

We can therefore write `\|pattern|s|foo|bar|`.

The address and editing commands are separate, so `\$pattern$s_foo_bar_` and `/pattern/s#foo#bar#` work as well.

Comment: Good discussion of parsing ambiguity, but sed *does* offer this feature if the first delimiter is preceded with backslash "\".

Comment: @bonsaiviking Very good point.

Answer (score 7):

You absolutely can use alternate delimiters for the matching address (`/regex/`), but you need to tell `sed` that you intend to do matching with that delimiter. The way you do this is with a leading backslash `\`. So your command can be:

```
sed -e '\|somevar|s|foo|bar|' config.h
```

or just as easily:

```
sed -e '\%somevar%s|foo|bar|' config.h
```

Reference: [POSIX reference for `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html#tag_04_126_13_02)

Answer (score 3):

My vote is for *feature*.

They are two different commands, the searching one `/.../` and the substitution one, `s/.../.../`. As far as I know it only lets change the separator of the substitution command.

In [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) is similar. You can do a regular expression search with `/.../` but if you want to change the separator you have to explicity mark it as a search with the `m`, like: `m|...|`.

I guess it will be related with some lexical parsing issue, but I don't know the reason, though.

Comment: You're on the right track, but sed uses "\" instead of `m` in this case.

Comment: @bonsaiviking: I didn't know that. I will thank you here and will upvote your answer that clarifies it.

Answer (score 2):

Feature. In

```
 sed -e '/somevar/s/foo/bar/' config.h
```

the `/somevar/` is an **address**. Addresses must be distinguishable from other functions, like `y` (yank), `i` (insert), `a` (append) and many more. In general, sed commands are parsed as

```
 [address[,address]]function[arguments]
```