# Append a URL contained in an env var at the end of certain lines of a file

Tags: regex, sed

I need to append a URL (`http://localhost:3128`) contained in the `$http_proxy` env var at the end of all the lines starting with `PATTERN` of a single file.

```
$ sed "/^PATTERN/ s/.*/& test/" somefile
```

It works quite well, but as soon as I replace `test` with `$http_proxy`, sed will complain because of the `//` inside it:

```
$ sed "/^PATTERN/ s/.*/& $http_proxy/" somefile
sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unknown option to `s'
```

So I tried using `#` as a separator (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9616287/1030960) for instance), but then `sed`doesn't have any effect, like if the pattern suddenly didn't match anymore:

```
$ sed "#^PATTERN# s#.*#& $http_proxy#" somefile
```

Any idea?

Comment: escape `\#` in range selector (first `#`) or use standard `/` for this range (and keep the `#` for `s` separator. you can also use `sed "s#^PATTERN.*#& $http_proxy#" somefile`

Comment: Don't use the word "pattern" as it's highly ambiguous. Are you searching for a number, a string, or a regexp? Do you want a partial match or a full match? If a full match, what delimits the section of text you are trying to match on - a number of characters, or a specific character or something else?

Comment: You've got correct answers already.  One extra tip is that you can simplify your pattern.  Try something like `sed "/pattern/s#$# $htttp_proxy#"`  You could escape the first dollar sign if you want, but at least in bash and sh, you don't need to.  If you're doing this in csh or tcsh, you might need to `sed "/pattern/s#"'$'"# $http_proxy#"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different sed delimiter in `s///` part only. And ypy don't need to put `&` in the replacement part since you're trying to append the string at the last, replacing the end of the line `$` would be enough.

```
sed "/^PATTERN/s~$~ $http_proxy~" somefile
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool that is unaffected by delimiters or variable content:

```
$ cat file
foo bar
PATTERN here
some line

$ awk -v pxy="$http_proxy" '/^PATTERN/{$0=$0" "pxy} 1' file             
foo bar
PATTERN here http://localhost:3128
some line
```

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808095/why-do-alternate-delimiters-not-work-with-sed-e-pattern-s-a-b#comment31198689_20808322) in this case the first delimiter has to be preceded with `\`:

```
$ sed "\#^PATTERN# s#.*#& $http_proxy#" somefile
```

Solves it indeed.