# Unterminated address regex error in bash script

Tags: bash, redhat

I want to edit the sshd_config file using bash script. However, I keep getting an error. I would appreciate any help given.

This is my script:

```
if ! grep "IgnoreRhosts" "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"; then
    sed -i /etc/ssh/sshd_config -e '/# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files/a IgnoreRhosts yes'
    printf "\e[32m IGNORERHOSTS YES ADDED\e[0m\n"
elif grep "#IgnoreRhosts yes" "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"; then
    sed -i 's/^#IgnoreRhosts yes/IgnoreRhosts yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    printf "\e[32mSUCCESSFULLY CHANGED\e[0m\n"
else
    printf "\e[32mNO CHANGES NEEDED\e[0m\n"
fi
```

This is the error I got:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated address regex
```

Script error line:

```
 sed -i /etc/ssh/sshd_config -e '/# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files/a IgnoreRhosts yes'
```

Comment: `'/# Don't ...` the second quote closes the first one ; you will want to escape inner quotes (`\'`)

Comment: You also need to escape `/` characters in the regexp.

Comment: Try `sed  -i -e '/# Don'\''t read the user'\''s ~\/.rhosts and ~\/.shosts files/a IgnoreRhosts yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```
sed -i /etc/ssh/sshd_config -e "\|# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files|a IgnoreRhosts yes"
```

Explanation:
 In this script I'm using `|` as a delimiter to make it more readable. This delimiter is defined by first `\` (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808095/why-do-alternate-delimiters-not-work-with-sed-e-pattern-s-a-b))

Then, I'm using double quotes instead of single quotes to avoid escaping apostrophes in words `Don't` and `user's`